# Xamarin Android java.lang.ClassNotFoundException only on Android 4.3 (api 17)

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin, manifest, classnotfoundexception

I have a project that works fine on Android 5.0 or above.

But i tried to run it on Android 4.3, and it crashes before starting the first activity.

Full error:

```
05-18 23:44:57.309 E/AndroidRuntime(27114): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mapsproject.ApplicationStartup" on path: /data/app/MapsProject.MapsProject-1.apk
```

The class that he didn't find is an Application. I use Android Support Library on my project, there's an SupportApplication or anything like this?

Below is my Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="MapsProject.MapsProject" android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="1.0.1" android:installLocation="auto">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.xamarin.docs.android.mapsproject.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
  <permission android:name="com.xamarin.docs.android.mapsproject.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <!--Location permissions-->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
  <!--Location permissions end-->
  <application android:label="MobileMapsProject" android:name="mapsproject.ApplicationStartup" android:allowBackup="true" android:debuggable="true">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyATpV7pH8ti6rJrnN01H4dbVeaMX2vJdvE" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <!--Facebook SDK-->
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"></meta-data>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/ApplicationName" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="MapsProject" android:theme="@style/MobileMapsTheme" android:name="md53f4bea8a426a59bffa9695091cc3f865.MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:theme="@style/MobileMapsTheme" android:name="md53f4bea8a426a59bffa9695091cc3f865.MainMapActivity" />
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAdActivity" />
    <service android:name="md59f70a99687498e7ba187118950981d26.KeepAliveService" />
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="2147483647" android:authorities="MapsProject.MapsProject.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
    <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
        <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.MapsProject.MapsProject" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:theme="@style/com_facebook_activity_theme" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" android:exported="true"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:theme="@style/com_facebook_activity_theme" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" android:exported="true"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity" />
    <!--Include the AdActivity and InAppPurchaseActivity configChanges and themes. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.IAPTheme" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:exported="false" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

And below is my class that is throwing the exception:

```
[Application(Name ="mapsproject.ApplicationStartup")]
    public class ApplicationStartup : Application
    {
        public static ApplicationStartup Current { get; private set; }
        public SqliteManager Manager { get; set; }
        SQLiteConnection conn;
        public ApplicationStartup(IntPtr handle, global::Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer)
            : base(handle, transfer) {
            Current = this;
        }
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();

            var sqliteFilename = "MapsDB.db3";
            string libraryPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var path = Path.Combine(libraryPath, sqliteFilename);
            conn = new SQLiteConnection(path);

            Manager = new SqliteManager(conn);
        }
    }
```

I've tried some tips on another threads, but it didn't solve the problem.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1:

Added full apk manifest.

Comment: What does your packaged Manifest contain?

Comment: By packaged Manifest you mean the full manifest that Xamarin generates when you run code?

Comment: Yes, the final manifest that ends up packaged into the apk, you can find it in a few places, like: `obj/Debug/android/manifest/AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: I've edited my question with the full manifest. See if you can find anything

Comment: @SushiHangover got nothing? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to JonDouglas on Xamarin Foruns i've found the solution.

Turns out to be a problem with Multidex enabled.

Android 5 or above handle multidex themselves, but versions below don't. So, i've found that my application activities was being generated on classes2.dex, and it should be on classes.dex, that way Android can find the application and start the app.
To see the classes.dex, i've used ClassyShark: https://github.com/google/android-classyshark

After knowing this problem, i've found that my multidex.keep (Found on `obj/Debug/multidex.keep`) was empty, so it was a problem. To solve this, i needed to go on android sdk build tools (`androidsdk\build-tools\25.0.3`), and open for edit **mainDexClasses.bat**.

So, i've found this piece of code:

```
if DEFINED output goto redirect
call "%java_exe%" -Djava.ext.dirs="%frameworkdir%" com.android.multidex.MainDexListBuilder "%disableKeepAnnotated%" "%tmpJar%" "%params%"
goto afterClassReferenceListBuilder
:redirect
call "%java_exe%" -Djava.ext.dirs="%frameworkdir%" com.android.multidex.MainDexListBuilder "%disableKeepAnnotated%" "%tmpJar%" "%params%" 1>"%output%"
:afterClassReferenceListBuilder
```

and change to:

```
SET params=%params:'=%  
if DEFINED output goto redirect  
call "%java_exe%" -Djava.ext.dirs="%frameworkdir%" com.android.multidex.MainDexListBuilder %disableKeepAnnotated% "%tmpJar%" %params%  
goto afterClassReferenceListBuilder  
:redirect
call "%java_exe%" -Djava.ext.dirs="%frameworkdir%" com.android.multidex.MainDexListBuilder %disableKeepAnnotated% "%tmpJar%" %params% 1>"%output%"  
:afterClassReferenceListBuilder
```

This way, the build tool could handle the multidex.keep file correctly.

After this, i've rebuilded the project, and multidex.keep was correctly generated. So, i copied the text inside the file and created my own multidex.keep file on solution.

To do this, i've added a text file on android project, naming it **multidex.keep**. I've pasted the values of the generated multidex.keep on the new file, and moved my activities to the top.
So, i've opened the multidex.keep file properties, and set Build Action to **MultiDexMainDexList**.

After this, i've rebuilded the project, and the classes.dex was generated correctly, this way i could run my app on android 4.4!

Here are the links i've found out the solutions:
http://www.jon-douglas.com/2016/09/05/xamarin-android-multidex/